# Bootstrap accordion collapse height issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i have been using the collapse module for a while but have now found an issue with items that are quite long eg. more than a few paragraphs.

It seems that depending upon the number of items you have a height attribute is added to the outermost div as per below:

```
 div class="accordion in collapse" id="accordion2" style="height: 348px;"
```

So when you expand an item it only expands to the height given above. If I un-check this whilst in developer mode it all works perfectly.

What I can't find is where in the bootstrap.js it adds this style attribute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
$('#accordion2').collapse('show').height('auto');
```

Answer (score 8):

I work myself

```
.collapse.in {
      height: auto !important;
}
```